# How to set a default value for command line parameter for git alias?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am trying to add an alias in `.gitconfig` which should resolve to a default value if there is not a command line argument.

```
lgs = "!f() { git log --stat $1; }; f"
```

`git lgs` should print the stat logs for the last commit.
`git lgs -2` - should print the stat logs for the last 2 commit. ( This one is working ).

I have tried a few options but no result

- `lgs = "!f() { git log --stat $1:=-1; }; f"`
- `lgs = "!f() { git log --stat $1:-1; }; f"`
- `lgs = "!f() { git log --stat $1=-1; }; f"`

How can I implement it correctly ?

Comment: This probably depends a bit on your shell. Assuming bash would give `lgs = "!f() { git log --stat ${1:=-1}; }; f"` for the usual bash default value

Comment: f() { git log --stat ${1:=-1}; }; f: 1: f() { git log --stat ${1:=-1}; }; f: 1: bad variable name

Comment: @Vogel612: Git aliases are run by a POSIX-style shell (`sh`) and sh has those same kinds of defaults, though rather than assigning, you'd just expand: `${1:--1}` in this case, if you want to make an empty-but-set `$1` expand to `-1`, or `${1--1}` if you want to have set-but-empty `$1` expand to the empty string.

Comment: Yeah , it worked. Put it as an answer please. `lgs = "!f() { git log --stat ${1:--1}; }; f"`

Comment: @torek since you seem to definitively know (and OP confirmed it works), you might want to post that as an answer instead :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `${1--1}` here, I think.

#### Explanation

Git aliases are run by a POSIX-style shell (`sh`).  POSIX shell has:

```
${variable-default}
```

and:

```
${variable:-default}
```

as expansion options, where if `$variable` is not set, you get the `default` instead.  The `:-` variant, which looks a bit like one of those old-style emoticons, means "use the default if the variable is set but expands to the empty string".

In most cases we use variable *names* here, e.g.:

```
somevar=somevalue
```

or:

```
anothervar=$(git ls-files --stage -- file.ext)
```

for instance, and then we'd have `${somevar-default}`.  But `$1` is the first positional parameter, `$2` is the second, and so on, and these work in these positions as well.

The default you want in this case is `-1` so `${1--1}`, which admittedly looks funny, works.

Note that [Vogel612's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034221/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-command-line-parameter-for-git-alias?noredirect=1#comment123801408_70034221) was very close, as these shells do also have:

```
${variable=default}
```

and:

```
${variable:=default}
```

which behave similarly (expanding to the default if the variable is unset, and in the second case if the variable is set to the empty string as well) but also have the side effect of *setting* the variable.  This is particularly useful when used with the no-op `:` (colon) command:

```
f() {
    local name="$1" email="$2"
    : ${name:="default name"} ${email:="<default.email@somewhere.com>"}
    # now you can refer to "$name" and "$email";
    # they are set and non-empty, even if someone passed the
    # empty string as arguments 1 and/or 2.
}
```

(Unfortunately the `local` construct, while *very* widely available and generally a good idea, is not in POSIX `sh`.  I was surprised to discover this recently.  It keeps the variable from "escaping" the scope of the function.  Fortunately, for one-off functions in Git aliases, it's not needed.)

Comment: Yup. e.g. `git config --global alias.lgdo '!f(){ git log --graph --decorate --oneline "${@---all}"; }; f'` to supply a no-args default set.

Comment: Would a numbered argument ever "expand to the empty string" so that `${1-default}` is different from `${1:-default}`?